# How to check available libraries and version numbers from https://maven.google.com

Tags: android, maven, gradle-dependencies

Ever since Google hosted its libraries in the new Google Maven Repository I'm having trouble keeping my dependencies up to date.

How can I check which libraries are availalbe in `maven.google.com`? In addition how can I see all the available version numbers of a particular library if I can't just browse the https://maven.google.com URL?

Any alternatives apart from navigating to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven
And checking the Website every time?

Comment: Android Studio already highlights dependencies hosted on `maven.google.com` that have a newer version.

Comment: I'm using Android Studio 2.3.3 and it doesn't do that. It only highlights newer versions from the local repo inside Android SDK and not from maven repo.

Comment: Yeah, you probably want to use a version of Android Studio released after `maven.google.com` came into existence, i.e., a 3.0 version.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know but I don't wanna mess with Android studio 3 yet since it's still in beta (if I'm not mistaken). Actually I found this link https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/master-index.xml that lists all the libraries but I still don't know how to see the available versions of each one. I guess I will keep checking the website until Android Studio 3 goes stable.

Comment: I would suggest to take a look at [versions-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/display-dependency-updates-mojo.html) it might help here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that my prayers have been heard. You can now browse

https://maven.google.com and check available libraries and version numbers.

Related post here https://plus.google.com/+IanLake/posts/gJ4SuhDhpgC