How to access and browse libraries in the Google Maven repository?
I encountered a problem when trying to access the Google Maven repository. Specifically, I received a 404 error when attempting to visit the URL https://maven.google.com/. I'm unsure if the repository has migrated elsewhere or if there have been any official announcements regarding this issue.
I've searched for any official announcements regarding changes to the Google Maven repository but haven't found any. Could someone provide guidance on how to access and browse the available libraries in the Google Maven repository?
I noticed some previous answers (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46942507 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/76053374/9793435) that suggests accessing the repository directly, but it seems I'm unable to do so.

What I've Tried:
I attempted to access the Google Maven repository directly through the URL https://maven.google.com/, but encountered a 404 error.
Expectations:
I would like to access and browse the libraries in the Google Maven repository similar to how I browse libraries on other repositories like https://mvnrepository.com/.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Why you are accessing Maven repository via browser ? Check this https://mvnrepository.com/

When I access https://maven.google.com/ in my browser I'm redirected to https://maven.google.com/web/index.html and see artefacts there.

@GeroldBroser I'm also redirected to maven.google.com/web/index.html but I encountered a 404 error there (Check my screenshot), did you encounter the 404 error?

@MaveňツI want to access Google Maven repository, refer to https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler:google() , not mvnrepository.com
